# Call method just after object creation

Tags: python, multithreading, constructor

Consider the following example code:

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_listening()

    def start_listening(self):
        while True:
            pass
```

I assume that the object will be never created this way.

When I create a new Server object, I want the start_listening() method to be called just after the constructor execution is over and the object has been created.

I do NOT want to call the method manually as below:

```
s = Server()
s.start_listening()
```

What should I do? Should I create a new thread inside init()?

Also, let's say that in place of start_listening() which actually never terminates, we could have a very slow method that we definitely want outside of the constructor.

What is a proper way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could derive or aggregate.

Deriving:

```
class AutoServer(Server):
    def __init__(self):
        Server.__init__(self)
        self.start_listening()
```

Aggregating:

```
class AutoServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = Server()
        self.server.start_listening()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do a function within a function and don't necessarily need the self.start_listening. Just be sure to indent it properly.

So:

```
Class Server: 
  def init(self): 
      def start_listening(self):
          while true:   
          pass
```